# How would I make a time limit before a certain command is carried out while letting the use interface with the current commands?

Tags: loops, batch-file

I was wondering how I could make a "ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul" go in the backround and when it finishes goto failed while the user is still able to work with a different set of commands.

Example)

I want the user to do this...

```
:start
set /p input=-
if %input%==ping goto ping
goto start
```

While this happens....

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul
goto exit
```

And make the above script run in the backround.

Comment: The IP `1.1.1.1` is now taken by CloudFlare, so this will not wait for 20s but return in some ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a separate cmd process using the `start` command. The process will run in the background, but will pop up a separate window and won't be able to interact with your current running batch file (unless you have them communicate through something like temporary files, for example).

The syntax is

```
start cmd /c [command]
```

So for your example, it can be

```
start cmd /c ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul
```

The goto won't work, of course, since it won't be running in the context of the current batch file. But you can create another batch file, or add command-line arguments to yours to control execution flow, and then run that as your command.

Comment: Thankyou, I guess the old temp file will have to do.